# Frozen mock's property is getting overwritten

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, autofixture

I'm having an issue where AutoFixture seems to be overwriting a property on a frozen mock.  The property on the mocked class is read-only, and from what I've read, AutoFixture shouldn't be trying to do anything with it.

I've included code to reproduce the issue in LINQPad below. `Victim` is a trivial test class with two read-only properties.  At issue is that once I have set the expectation for the `Things` property and registered the mock's `Object` as the instance for AutoFixture to return for the `Victim` type, the collection `Things` contains different strings.

To reproduce the problem, run the code below in LINQPad as a *C# Program* and reference *AutoFixture* and *Moq* from NuGet. Be sure to include the namespaces *Moq* and *Ploeh.AutoFixture*.

My expectation is that I should get back the object I registered with `Register` and that the collection `Things` in the returned `Victim` should return the collection I referenced in my call to `SetupGet`.

```
public class Victim
{
    private string _vic;
    private IEnumerable<string> _things;
    public virtual string VictimName { get { return _vic; } }
    public virtual IEnumerable<string> Things { get { return _things; } }
}

void Main()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture();
    var victimName = fixture.CreateAnonymous("VIC_");
    var things = fixture.CreateMany<string>();
    victimName.Dump("Generated vic name");
    things.Dump("Generated things");

    var victimMock = fixture.Freeze<Mock<Victim>>();
    victimMock.SetupGet(x => x.VictimName).Returns(victimName).Verifiable();
    victimMock.SetupGet(x => x.Things).Returns(things).Verifiable();
    fixture.Register(() => victimMock.Object);

    var victim = fixture.CreateAnonymous<Victim>();
    (victim.Equals(victimMock.Object)).Dump("Victims are the same?");
    victim.VictimName.Dump("Returned name");
    victim.Things.Dump("Returned things");
    (things.Equals(victim.Things)).Dump("Returned things are the same?");

    victimMock.Verify();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that the *Iterator* for `Things` is actually the same, but that the strings it generates are different. This is [actually by design](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/04/18/EnumerablesAreDynamicalsoInAutoFixture.aspx), although we've later come to realize that this wasn't a particularly good design decision.

In [AutoFixture 3, this behavior has been changed](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/wiki/AutoFixture-3.0-Release-Notes).

If I've guessed correctly, this issue will go away in AutoFixture 3. In AutoFixture 2 you should be able to resolve it by creating the fixture like this:

```
var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new StableMultipeCustomization());
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that the *iterator was a generator*. I just expected subsequent calls to `CreateMany` for a frozen type would return a different sequence. That clears up a lot; thanks for the help.

Comment: By the way, the `StableMultipeCustomization` is not a typo, and is defined in the blog post that Mark referenced above; it is not included in AutoFixture 2.16.2 (which is what I'm using).